# Cannot connect to the Web3 provider when rpccorsdomain is on

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, remix, private-blockchain, rpc

I am getting the message:

```
 Not possible to connect to the Web3 provider. Make sure the provider is running and a connection is open (via IPC or RPC).
```

When I specify:

```
--rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:8000"
```

I am following also [this](https://github.com/ethereum/remix/issues/588) thread but I have no solutions. I am

- Not connecting to remix via Http
- Changing the order of the parameters
- changing between localhost and 127.0.0.1 (because apparently it makes a difference when connecting the etherparty block explorer)